# No such file or directory when run as service?

Tags: go

When i run my application from terminal `sudo -u www-data ./scarga` and open browser, the template file served well, everything ok. Command executed from `/var/www/html/scarga.local/` directory.

When i run my application as `sudo service scarga start` it says: `open ./resources/views/index.html: no such file or directory`

File with HTTP handler: https://pastebin.com/MU7YDAWV

The scarga.service file: https://pastebin.com/eBL3jJFx

Tree of project: https://pastebin.com/rFVa8A3P

Rights for `index.html file`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 3586 Jun 28 14:27 index.html`

**Why this happens and how to solve?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the correct working directory in your script using `WorkingDirectory=` - presumably:

```
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/scarga.local
```

Comment: Thanks, put this in `[Service]` section, now everything perfect.